# iptables open port failed

Tags: iptables

I want to open 5627 port on 127.0.0.1 with the following command

before

```
$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45426           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3260            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35357           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8773            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8774            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8775            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8776            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:27017     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3260                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN

$ netstat -tln | grep 5672
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Open port 5672 for 127.0.0.1

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -ptcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
```

Show port 5672

```
$ netstat -tln | grep 5672
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*
```

127.0.0.1:5672 is not open. How can I open local address 127.0.0.1:5672 ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`netstat` does not display ports that are open by `iptables` .  It displays ports being listened to by a running program.  You need to reconfigure your program to listen to 127.0.0.1, and then `netstat` will display it as "LISTENING".

Answer (score 0):

The `netstat` command is showing what ports have a *process* listening on them.  The `iptables` command manipulates port filtering in the kernel.  Changes you make with `iptables` will not show up in the `netstat` command.

However, since you have a process listening on tcp6 :::5672 then this will *also* listen on the IPv4 port automatically.